# Is it possible to hide header on child pages?

Tags: css, wordpress, header, single-page-application

I built a new website in single page design but still want to link to further information on child pages. Can I use a different header-style there or is it possible to hide it completely?

I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: The answer is YES by using the body tag... but how are we supposed to supply a solution without seeing your pages code?

Comment: I used visual composer because it's the first page I ever built. I thought it could be possible by using custom css. Where can I see the page code? Is it the template full width.php in the editor you need to see?

Comment: Google "how to find visual composer source code"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing a custom css plugin for single pages
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/
After activating you are able to add costum css on a selected page. 
With

```
header {display:none;}
navmenu {display:none;}
```

it works!!